# (Function) Swaping two numbers in c

Tags: c, function, if-statement, swap

I'm trying to write a program that swaps two numbers. I was trying to revise my codes but still the answer won't show. Pls help and thanks in advance.

The variables are *x*,*y* and *z* with values of *10*, *-1* and *5*. Hence: *x=10*, *y=-1* and *z=5*. The expected **output** must be *x=-1*, *y=5* and *z=10*. As you can see, the order is from the *lowest number up to the largest one*. So please correct my codes and I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11 as my compiler. P.S. swap's formulas must not be altered according to my instructor. (Though maybe you know it)

Here is the codes that I made:

```
void swap(int *px, int *py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
int main(void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    x=10;
    y=-1;
    z=5;

    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",x,y,z);
    if(x>y)
    {
        x=y;
    }
    else if(y>z)
    {
        y=z;
    }
    else if(z>x)
    {
        z=x;
    }
    swap(&x,&y);
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

Again the **expected output** must be:

```
x=-1, y=5, z=10
```

Comment: **Did you compile with warnings enabled**. You do not even provide all 3 variables to your `printf`! And you are supposed to use `swap` in all of those `if`'s.

Comment: And for what is more important: There isn't a **Dev-C++ 5.11** compiler.

Comment: Posters don't build and test homework any more.  That stage is bypassed and the dysfunctional source copy/pasted direct to SO :(

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah. I forgot. My mistake and sorry

Comment: @Joel Yes there is a 5.11 compiler in Dev-C++.

Comment: @MartinJames What do you mean by SO?

Comment: @CarbineAlejandro as you said **in**

Comment: @Joel I mean the versions of Dev-C++ to be clear. My mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
// Make sure x is smaller than y
if(x>y)
{
    swap(&x, &y);
}

// Make sure x is smaller than z
if(x>z)
{
    swap(&x, &z);                      
} 
// Now x is smaller than both y and z

// Make sure y is smaller than z
if(y>z)
{
    swap(&y, &z);
}
```

So the full program would look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *px, int *py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
int main(void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    x=10;
    y=-1;
    z=5;

    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",x,y,z);

    // Make sure x is smaller than y
    if(x>y)
    {
        swap(&x, &y);
    }

    // Make sure x is smaller than z
    if(x>z)
    {
        swap(&x, &z);                      
    } 
    // Now x is smaller than both y and z

    // Make sure y is smaller than z
    if(y>z)
    {
        swap(&y, &z);
    }

    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> x=10 y=-1 z=5
>
> x=-1 y=5 z=10

Comment: Let me try the one you've proposed

Comment: The output and given is the same. Does it lack something?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much for helping. I know it is a basic problem for you but I find it hard though. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this exercise is to write a bunch of conditionals that use the `swap()` function to order the elements from lowest to highest.

At no point in this code should you be using assignment - you're going to overwrite one value with another, losing that original value that was overwritten:

```
if(x>y)
{
    x=y;
}
```

Remember, the idea here is to use swaps.

Comment: So how should I do it? If "if-statements" overwrite each other then what should it be?

Comment: 'If statements' don't overwrite anything - what you do with them does, and in this case, you have the statement `x = y;`. So whatever value was in `x` is lost, and is replaced with y's value. That's what's doing the overwriting. Instead, maybe you should use swaps. Before you write any code, think about this: If you have the list `{10, -1, 5}`, what order of swaps gets you to the list `{-1, 5, 10}`?

Comment: x swaps with z, y swaps with x?

Comment: Yeah, that works. Now, how would you put together a procedure that would sort `{x, y, z}`, for any arbitrary values of the three? If you have three values, what is the maximum number of comparisons and swaps you'll have to do to order them? What about `{10, 5, -1}`? How many possible combinations are there?

Comment: By using if statements or could be if-else statements and combining it with the swaps. As I have simulated, there are only 3 I think? Am I right?